# Why is private variable 'Named parameters cannot begin with an underscore.' gets the error?

Tags: flutter, dart

Can you explain why this code gives an error and the solution? appbar header color should be accessible only from this file

```
class AppBarTitleColor extends StatelessWidget {
  final Color _appBarTitleColor;
  const AppBarTitleColor({super.key, this._appBarTitleColor = Colors.black});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const AppBarTitleColor();
  }
}
```

I thought it might be related to 'final' or 'const' but my changes didn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot instantiate a **private variable (with underscore)** directly.

You need to implement it like below:

```dart
class AppBarTitleColor extends StatelessWidget {
  final Color _appBarTitleColor;

  const AppBarTitleColor({
    super.key,
    Color appBarTitleColor = Colors.black,
  }) : _appBarTitleColor = appBarTitleColor;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const AppBarTitleColor();
  }
}
```

Comment: why and what is the purpose of this code? Calling variable '_appBarTitleColor' does '_appBarTitleColor' = 'appBarTitleColor' ?

Comment: You can't initialize the widget with a private variable. For example, this would never work:

```dart
final AppBarTitleColor titleColor = AppBarTitleColor(_appBarTitleColor: Colors.blue);
```

What @Yash has done is used a `super` constructor. Since you can only initialize with a non-private variable, the constructor has been converted to use a public variable, then the value has been passed to the private variable.